# Why is the theoretical RAM limit for RHEL 6 128 TB and how is this determined?

Tags: rhel, memory, linux-kernel, ram, virtual-memory

I'm studying for RHCSA and am confused by a statement I came across in some training material:

> There is no practical maximum RAM, as theoretically, you could run 128 TB of RAM on RHEL 6.  But that's just theory.  The maximum RAM supported by Red Hat on RHEL 6 is 16 GB on 32-bit systems and 2 TB on 64-bit systems.

Can someone please explain where the 128 TB theoretical limit is coming from?  I'm confused on how the author knows the theoretical limit exists if RHEL 6 clearly defines other maximum limits.  Is this just factoring in the theoretical limits of 64-bit architecture? Or is there some other reason here?

Comment: [Here](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0812.2/00292.html) is the answer. You can rewrite it and insert as a answer

Answer (score 8):

From the kernel documentation, in [`Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt):

```
Virtual memory map with 4 level page tables:

0000000000000000 - 00007fffffffffff (=47 bits) user space, different per mm
```

2<sup>47</sup> bytes = 128TiB

Comment: 2^48 = 256 TiB ;-)

Comment: Very concise answer.

For more info see https://lwn.net/Articles/117783/

35 bits for the page table index and 4096 bytes (2^12) is the size of a page. Giving 2^(35)*2^(12)=2^47=128 TB

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer

Each Linux process can address at most 128 TB of [**virtual** memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). However, this is more than the Linux kernel can handle **physically**. Hence, this limit is theoretical.

It has probably been chosen arbitrarily, based on a supposed forseable "worst-case" usage scenario.

## Elaborated answer

You cannot actually use more RAM than your hardware allows (48 bits = *256 TB* [is common](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details) these days), and then you will be limited by the amount of physical memory the Linux kernel can handle.

For example, on the Intel *x86 64-bit* architecture, Linux cannot use more than **64 TB** of physical memory (since version *2.6.30*, but [it was](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=c898faf91b3ec6b0f6efa35831b3984fa3331db0) *16 TB* just before). Note that RHEL 6 uses a *2.6.32* kernel.

On the 64-bit [s390 architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_ESA/390), the [*same limit*](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=14045ebf1e1156d966a796cacad91028e01797e5) applies (since *2.6.28*). If you use 32-bit however, the limit is *4 GB*, but using a [strange](http://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/) trick called [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension), you may go up to *64 GB* (often used on x86).

I think other 64-bit architectures have lower limits.

See Red Hat [limits table](https://access.redhat.com/articles/rhel-limits) for more information (thanks *Huygens*).

Comment: The 48-bit limit on x86-64 is very much a hardware limit at this point. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details

Comment: Sure, but this is implementation dependant and can change in the future. The question is about a *theoretical* limit. I updated my answer though.

Comment: This is hardware implementation dependent. AMD and Intel x86_64 today's architecture support only 48 bit of address space. This architecture could evolve in the future.

Answer (score 1):

One should not mix up virtual memory and physical volatile memory. The former is CPU architecture specific and will be mapped to volatile and non-volatile memory. The latter, aka RAM, should be independent of CPU architecture from the kernel point of view.

Today's AMD and Intel x86_64 implementation *only* support 48 bit of addressable virtual memory. Which means that the kernel can address 2^48 = 256 TiB per process VM.
Linux kernel on x86_64 architecture split the addressable VM space in 2, 128 TiB for user space and 128 TiB for kernel space. So a process can theoretically address a total of 128 TiB of virtual memory.

The maximum of volatile physical memory that the kernel can handle is a different aspect, but I do not know this information.

**Regarding the RHCSA author statement**

The author of the statement "There is no practical maximum RAM, as theoretically, you could run 128 TB of RAM on RHEL 6." is using wrong or misunderstood terminology. [Here are the table from Red Hat web site summarizing the capabilities of RHEL 3, 4, 5 and 6](http://www.redhat.com/resourcelibrary/articles/articles-red-hat-enterprise-linux-6-technology-capabilities-and-limits). And they clearly state "Maximum x86_64 per-process virtual address space [...] 128TB [for RHEL 6]"

The same page states that RHEL 6 supports a maximum of 2TB/64TB RAM (physical volatile memory). I guess it means that it is certified for a 2TB max RAM, and theoretically could go up to 64TB. [SLES is much clearer in this respect](https://www.suse.com/products/server/technical-information/#Kernel).

Comment: You say a process can address 128 TB, but the whole system (several processes) may have and use more, so the sentence "you could run 128 TB of RAM on RHEL 6" seems awkward to me, especially given the fact that the official Linux kernel cannot...

Comment: Could you provide the pointer to where you found the statement "you could run 128 TB of RAM on RHEL 6"? I doubt it is from Red Hat them selves! The author is confusing physical memory and virtual memory.

Comment: @Totor I just updated my answer with a link to Red Hat's web site which does not confirm the RHCSA statement.

Comment: @Totor: On the Linux kernel, HIGHMEM has not be ported to 64-bit. Without HIGHMEM, all of the RAM is mapped into kernel address space, which is 128 TB, hence the limit.

Answer (score 0):

The other reason it is theoretical is the lack of implementation experience.

It's common for programmers to size variables far in advance of what hardware is capable of, so that the kernel doesn't need risky rip-and-replace programming as hardware of that capability appears a decade or more later.

However variable size isn't the only limit. Data structures and their algorithms impose their own limits. Imagine for a moment doing a linear walk of a data structure describing each 4KB page of that 128TB. There are some obvious responses: don't use 4KB pages, don't use a linear data structure, don't access those data structures often, offload as much as possible into the hardware. But there are more subtle data structure+algorithm limitations which we won't know until we encounter them.

We know that if we were to magically discover a 128TB PC tomorrow and try to boot Linux on it that it will perform terribly, and perhaps so terribly as not to start. But fixing the algorithms is trivial, fixing the data structures is some work but still much less work than fixing the size of a widely-understood variable. So we'll see changes of that nature as memory size grows.